# Android Fragment On Attached not called for tabs more than two

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hi i have a android tab bar activity with four tabs. Each tabs has a separate fragment class. and each class has a onAttach method. I want to add a broad cast receiver for all four fragment like this

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(ActiveBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("ActiveChat"));
    }


@Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(IncommingBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("Incommingchat"));
        }
```

I add all four fragment to view pager like this

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new IncommingFragment(), "Incoming");
        adapter.addFragment(new ActiveFragment(), "Active");
        adapter.addFragment(new OtherFragment(), "Other");
        adapter.addFragment(new WhoIsOnlineFragment(), "Online");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

When i run the project , only the first two fragments on-attach is called  (IncommingFragment and  ActiveFragment) the other two active fragments on Attach method is not called. can some one help me to fix this issue . tnx.

[image]

Comment: that's how the ViewPager works. Other fragments' onAttach will be called once you switch to next fragment. 3rd fragment will be attached once you enter the 2nd fragment.

Comment: Viewpager loads 2 fragments at a time.When you swipe through fragments they will load